# Rust compiler complaining of using moved value in loop when code is not

Tags: rust

Rust is complaining of using a moved value in a loop:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Animal {
    Dog,
    Cat,
}

fn dedup(animals: Vec<Animal>) -> Vec<Animal> {
    let mut stage = None;
    let mut outs = vec![];

    for x in animals {
        match stage {
            None => stage = Some(x),
            Some(a) => {
                if a != x {
                    outs.push(a);
                    stage = Some(x);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if let Some(a) = stage {
        outs.push(a);
    }
    outs
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
  --> src/lib.rs:14:18
   |
14 |             Some(a) => {
   |                  ^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
```

When I read this code, I see that `stage` is moved into `a`, which is then possibly pushed to `outs`, then never used again. Why is this a compiler error?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b563052bea83d628e9494d2aea905278)

Interestingly, the following alternative works:

```rust
            Some(a) if a != x => {
                    outs.push(a);
                    stage = Some(x);
            }
            _ => {}
```

Comment: N. B. You can write `dedup` without `stage` by simply matching on `outs.last()` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20a770d2159d38652927817e924e4d58)). Of course, if this isn't an exercise you should just call `Vec::dedup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
match stage {
    // ...
    Some(a) => {
        // ...
    }
}
```

you are *unconditionally* moving the value out of `stage`. It doesn't matter if the code in the block uses `a` or not; all Rust sees is that the `stage` is now invalidated, and cannot be used again.

The reason why

```
Some(a) if a != x => {
    outs.push(a);
    stage = Some(x);
}
```

works is because including the `if` in the pattern makes it a *conditional* move. The `a` is only moved out if `a != x`, and when that happens, `stage` is always reassigned.

Comment: To be extremely explicit, for people like me who missed the point about 5 times: when `stage` is `Some(a)` and `a == x`, in the original code, `stage` is moved out of and *not* immediately reassigned, so it can't be moved out of again next iteration.